# Memory allocation in array of java

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management

I want to know how Java allocates memory for arrays: Is it contiguous or non-contiguous?
Please give me a suitable example which proves it.

Comment: ...and I'm assuming you've done exhaustive research of your own before asking this?

Comment: Because i can prove memory allocation is contigeous in c,c++ but i am not able to prove it is contigeous.which i think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java specs do not require either choice, and in fact do not offer any way of observing either choice.

If I write a JVM in Javascript, for example, arrays would probably be non-contiguous.

That said, I would strongly assume that most actual JVMs do use contiguous memory.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of telling, since even using JNI insulates you from the actual implementation.

That being said, it is probably true that most practical implementations allocate array elements as contiguous internal blocks of memory.

Comment: Then can i say? there is no any methode to find out solution that memory allocation is contiguous.

Comment: The point in Java is that you _shouldn't care._

Answer (score 0):

Java matrices are arrays of arrays, for example first row can be 10-elements while second row cen be 40 element long. I think it is not contiguous when not being square-matrix. But you can be sure when iterating through last index-block it is contiguous.

```
 a[100][500][64]

 a[5][5][0 to 63] contiguous

 a[5][0 to 5][5] not contiguous

 a[0 to 5][5][5] not contiguous and maybe there will be cache-critical stalls
```

Answer (score 0):

In most JVMs the entire heap is continous, so you can reasonably assume that arrays are allocated continously.

Note: Even if an Array of references are continuous, but the objects they reference could be anywhere.  They will probably be together but they might not me.

e.g.

```
String[] strings = "a,b,c,d,e,f".split(",");
```

Strings is an array of references, the individual String objects and their `char[]` objects could be anywhere. Note: all the Strings are likely to use the same `char[]`